# What exactly will Amazon return if asked to list all the buckets?

Tags: amazon-s3

As I have to parse it, I must know what the returning data will be structured into?

Answer (score 2):

The GET operation on the Service endpoint (s3.amazonaws.com) returns a list of all of the buckets owned by the authenticated sender of the request.

Sample Request:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: s3.amazonaws.com
Date: Wed, 01 Mar  2009 12:00:00 GMT
Authorization: AWS 15B4D3461F177624206A:xQE0diMbLRepdf3YB+FIEXAMPLE=
```

Sample Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ListAllMyBucketsResult xmlns="http://doc.s3.amazonaws.com/2006-03-01">
  <Owner>
    <ID>bcaf1ffd86f461ca5fb16fd081034f</ID>
    <DisplayName>webfile</DisplayName>
  </Owner>
  <Buckets>
    <Bucket>
      <Name>quotes;/Name>
      <CreationDate>2006-02-03T16:45:09.000Z</CreationDate>
    </Bucket>
    <Bucket>
      <Name>samples</Name>
      <CreationDate>2006-02-03T16:41:58.000Z</CreationDate>
    </Bucket>
  </Buckets>
</ListAllMyBucketsResult>
```

Source: [S3 REST API » Operations on the Service » GET Service](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/API/index.html?RESTBucketGET.html)

Answer (score 1):

The S3 API is described [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/API/index.html?RESTBucketGET.html).